# werkzeug.security generate_password_hash alternative without SHA-1

Tags: python, flask, sha1, werkzeug

I use `generate_password_hash` from `werkzeug.security` to hash and salt my passwords. I recently saw [this article about SHA-1 collisions](http://shattered.io/). `werkzeug.security` uses SHA-1 and since it is not as safe any more I would like an alternative. How can I hash my passwords without relying on SHA-1?

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
generate_password_hash(secret)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**The use of SHA-1 in `generate_password_hash` is not vulnerable**, as it is only used as an intermediate, iterated step in the PBKDF2 hash. [See the discussion in chat.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35836840#35836840)

> when you're chaining zillions of hashes as in PBKDF2 the risk is indistinguishable from someone breaking a strong password by pure chance.

There was further discussion on the [cryptography-dev](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cryptography-dev/2017-March/000737.html) mailing list.

> You're correct that HMAC's security is still fine when used with SHA-1,
> HMAC-MD5 is even secure believe it or not.

---

[`generate_password_hash`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/utils/#werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash) takes a `method` argument to customize how the hash is generated. The default is `pbkdf2:sha1`. Pass a different derivation method for PBKDF2.

```
generate_password_hash(secret, method='pbkdf2:sha512')
```

You can also change the number of iterations from the default of 150,000 to a higher number, at the cost of a slower hash speed. `pbkdf2:sha1:200000`.

---

You're probably okay with PBKDF2, as long as the hash and iterations are tuned well. Alternatively, use [Passlib](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which supports more hash methods than Werkzeug. See Passlib's [recommended hashes](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/narr/quickstart.html#choosing-a-hash) for discussion on which hashes to use. This example shows how to use bcrypt with Passlib.

```
pip install passlib bcrypt
```

```
from passlib.context import CryptContext
crypt_context = CryptContext(schemes=['bcrypt_sha256'])
crypt_context.hash(secret)
```